# Java weka DataSource loading issue with RESTful Web Service

Tags: web-services, datasource, weka, restful-url, java-ee-7

I'm doing a prediction sytem application by using the weka APi with java.
I created a JavaSE application with weka and use following code for load the dataset

> String filepath = "";
>
> DataSource source = new DataSource(filepath);

when I try to implement it with restful web service JavaEE
it gives an error at that line as folowing

*java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils$DataSource*

can some one help me

Answer (score 0):

If some one having this problem,

Please re-check whether you set the weka.jar file path in to your web service. 
*Specially if you add the weka.jar file to the build path of your web service project it doesn't add to the hosting web service only for the application environment.*

Make sure to add the file in to **WebContent** -> **WEB-INF** -> **lib** -> weka.jar

Then It will works fine.